# Transfer of large number of files using SFTP is slow in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am uploading 4000 zip files of size 85 KB of each using over Linux Server using SFTP in C# WPF application.
This whole process takes 30 minutes.

Is there any way to speed up the uploading using SFTP?

I'm using WinSCP .NET assembly:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

I had also used Chilkat previously.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WinSCP;
namespace SFTP_Demo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string line;
            SessionOptions sessionoptions = new SessionOptions()
            {
                Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "172.168.1.7",
                PortNumber = 22,
                UserName = "lduser",
                Password = "lduser",
                GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true
            };
            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                session.Open(sessionoptions);
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(txtFile.Text);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"D:\Test\signature\ldoutput\"+line, "/SFTP/", false, transferOptions);
                    transferResult.Check();
                    counter++;
                    strbldr = strbldr.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} Upload of {1} succeeded", counter + 1.ToString(), line));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite an overhead with each file (opening, closing, updating timestamps). So the transfer of a large number of small files is pretty inefficient.

What you can do, is to parallelize the transfer.

Collect the list of files using [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) (or [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) if you need recursion) and split the list to batches, transferring each in a separate thread.

See this example:
[Automating download in parallel connections over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers)